# How to get the name of IntegerChoices

Tags: python, django

I have these `models.InterChoices`

```
class LogType(models.IntegerChoices):

    SYSTEM_OK = 1
    SYSTEM_REPLY = 2
    SYSTEM_ERROR = 5
```

I can get choices for select box such as `LogType.choices()`

Now, I want to get the `name`

For example, I want to do this

`LogType.get_by_id(1)` return `SYSTEM_OK` or `System Ok`

is it possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the constructor of the `LogType`, so:

```
item = LogType(1)
```

You can then use `item.label`, or `item.name` to get the name. For example:

```
>>> item = LogType(1)
>>> item.label
'System Ok'
>>> item.name
'SYSTEM_OK'
```